# Raytracing camera rotates in wrong directions

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I'm trying to build a raytracer and I use [this article](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-generating-camera-rays/generating-camera-rays) on how to build camera system.
 The problem is that when, after calculating ray direction in camera space, I multiply it by camera-to-world transformation matrix and my camera seems to rotate in wrong (opposite) directions and works correctly if I inverse transformation matrix before multiplication.
Here is the code (I use glm library and right-handed coordinate system).
Initial data:

```
glm::vec3 origin_ = glm::vec3(0.f);// camera origin
cont glm::vec3 kDirection = glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, -1.f);
cont glm::vec3 kUp = glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
float aspect_ratio_ = (float)raster_height_ / raster_width_;

// bug !!! rotates in opposite direction  (camera is actually tilted down)
glm::mat4 camera_to_world_ = glm::lookAtRH(origin_, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.2f, -1.f), kUp);
// works !!! (camera is tilted up)
glm::mat4 camera_to_world_ = glm::inverse(glm::lookAtRH(origin_, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.2f, -1.f), kUp));
```

And function that generates camera rays

```
// Calculate ray as if camera is located at 0,0,0 and pointing into negative z direction
// Then transform ray direction to desired plase
// x,y - pixel coordinates of raster image
// calculate as if raster image (screen) is 1.0 unit away from origin (eye)
Ray Camera::GenRay(const uint32_t x, const uint32_t y) {
  glm::vec3 ray_direction = kDirection;
  // from raster space to NDC space
  glm::vec2 pixel_ndc((x + 0.5f) / raster_width_, (y + 0.5f) / raster_height_);
  // from NDC space to camera space
  float scale = tan(fov_ / 2.0f);
  ray_direction.x = (2.0f * pixel_ndc.x - 1.0f) * scale; // *aspect_ratio_;
  ray_direction.y = (1.0f - 2.0f * pixel_ndc.y) * scale * aspect_ratio_;
  // apply camera-to-world rotation matrix to direction
  ray_direction = camera_to_world_ * glm::vec4(ray_direction, 0.0f);

  return  Ray(origin_, ray_direction, Ray::Type::kPrimary);
}
```

I really can't understand the root of a problem so any help us appreciated.

Comment: Because `lookAt` produces the world-to-camera matrix, i.e. you multiply a world point by it to get the camera space point, and it *is* the "inverse" matrix you are talking about.